# Are there semantic reasoners which are compatible with the Web Ontology Language, running natively on the Mac?

Tags: macos, artificial-intelligence, semantics, owl, reasoning

I am curious about this and want to experiment. But I am a Mac user and all I could find was Java-based. I can't run Java applications on my Mac for an unknown reason and I'd prefer something native.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FaCT++](http://code.google.com/p/factplusplus/) is a DL reasoner which supports OWL DL and (partially) OWL 2. It is implemented in C++ and there are OS X binaries available for [download](http://code.google.com/p/factplusplus/downloads/list).

But in general I'd recommend you to fix your Java infrastructure on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Racer Pro](http://www.racer-systems.com/products/download/) has a native interface on Mac OS X. It is not free though: [license scheme](http://www.racer-systems.com/products/licenses.phtml). You can request a trial license.

I agree with Kaarel though; you may want to fix your Java on Mac first. See if you can find anything in the [Java security updates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1222).